# .Length in arrays and (i, arr[i])

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

Here is the piece of code that I want to understand:-

```
    function listArrayItems(arr) {
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(i, arr[i])
    }
}
var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink'];
listArrayItems(colors);
```

I don't get what is the .length even though I searched and google gave me this
The length property returns an integer value that represents the number of characters in the string. If the string is an empty string, the length property will return 0.
and also I don't understand the console.log(i, arr[i])
Thank you.***

Comment: You should have read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length, not https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's simple,

**console.log(i, arr[i])** means, here "**i**" represents your current index in loop and "**arr[i]**" indicates the value of the appropriate index in iterations.

in the output, you can see,

```
i arr[i]
==========
0 'red'
1 'orange'
2 'yellow'
3 'green'
4 'blue'
5 'purple'
6 'pink'
```

Hope you get clear idea about it.